# How to read stringified JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json

Kindly need your help as this really taking me long time to try.
From JSP, I passed the stingnify JSON object as a String to the Java action, it like

```
String jsonDealer = [{"dealerID":"VARSSWK103","dealerName":"NPD STATION SDN BHD"},
{"dealerID":"VARSSTH008","dealerName":"Winjaya Teleshop"}]
```

How I can convert this to JSON object/ or ArrayList of Dealer, so that I can retrieve the dealer ID and dealer name?

Thanks for all help!!!

Answer (score -1):

Well you could write your own JSON parser, but there's no need to re-invent the wheel - there are a number of robust, mature JSON parsers freely available. I use [JSONObject](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/json/JSONObject.html)  and [JSONArray](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/json/JSONArray.html)  from Tapestry. If you [download](http://tapestry.apache.org/download.html) Tapestry 5 and unpack it, then just include the library `tapestry-core-5.0.18.jar` in your build path and you'll be set to go. Both JSONObject and JSONArray take a String as constructor argument, and the api is fully documented in those links.

Answer (score -1):

using http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ can be realy easy.

See http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/snippets.html

```
String str = "{'dealerName':'NPD STATION SDN BHD', 'dealerID': 1, 'dealerReputation': 2.0, 'dealerActive': true}";  
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( str );
```

and

```
String str = "['NPD STATION SDN BHD', 1, 2.0, true]";  
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON( str );
```