# Google charts API JSON not valid

Tags: java, json, google-visualization

The following code returns json for Google chart

```
public static DataTable generateDataTable(){
        // Create a data table,
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        ArrayList cd = new ArrayList();
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("name", ValueType.TEXT, "Animal name"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("link", ValueType.TEXT, "Link to wikipedia"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("population", ValueType.NUMBER, "Population size"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("vegeterian", ValueType.BOOLEAN, "Vegetarian?"));

        data.addColumns(cd);

        // Fill the data table.
        try {
          data.addRowFromValues("Aye-aye", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aye-aye", 100, true);
          data.addRowFromValues("Sloth", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth", 300, true);
          data.addRowFromValues("Leopard", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopard", 50, false);
          data.addRowFromValues("Tiger", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger", 80, false);
        } catch (TypeMismatchException e) {
          System.out.println("Invalid type!");
        }


        return data;
}

public static void main(String []args){
    String json = JsonRenderer.renderDataTable(generateDataTable(), false, false).toString();
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

But the returned JSON

```
{cols:[{id:'name',label:'Animal name',type:'string',pattern:''},{id:'link',label:'Link to wikipedia',type:'string',pattern:''},{id:'population',label:'Population size',type:'number',pattern:''},{id:'vegeterian',label:'Vegetarian?',type:'boolean',pattern:''}]}
```

is not valid when pasted into http://jsonlint.com/

Also what is the pattern value that shows up in the returned json `{id:'name',label:'Animal name',type:'string',**pattern:''**}`

Comment: This is a bug to report to Google

Comment: Bug Report: http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-java/issues/detail?id=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys.

I solved it by using Jackson which can quote the unquoted keys

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;  

JsonNode root = null;
String json = JsonRenderer.renderDataTable(generateDataTable(), true, false).toString();

        try{
            JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createJsonParser(json)
                .enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES)
                .enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES);
                 root = new ObjectMapper().readTree(parser);
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }

        response.getWriter().println(root.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

What `Google` is sending you is a `JavaScript object` and not `JSON`.

You need to figure out a way to `stringfy` the `JavaScript object` to  `JSON`.

Have a look at the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437213/how-to-read-stringified-json-string-in-java) question. It might help you.